# Matplotlib canvas doesn't embed in wx panel

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, wxnotebook

I'm writing a class to embed some common configurations of graphs in a wx `Notebook` tab, but I'm running into a strange issue.  When I try to add `wx.Panel` with the `FigureCanvas`, instead it floats the figure in another window entirely.

[image: example]

The odd thing is, the graph window resizes when I resize the main window.  The figure comes out the correct size, just not in the right window.

My code is [here](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/a994fd95daad5c12c853).  I can't see what I'm doing wrong, I've embedded matplotlib in wx before, but never in a `Notebook`.  I can get it to embed on a simple GUI by itself just fine, just not in the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. Make `GraphTab` a `wxPanel` rather than a `wxFrame`
2. Set all `GraphTab` to have `nb` as the parent (currently your first one has `self` as the parent.

I'm not sure whether this is everything, but it's a start.

Comment: It was the super class of `GraphTab`.  I knew it had to be something simple, and to be honest I thought I already had it as a `Panel`, so I didn't think to look at that as the problem.  As for the second point that was probably just a copy/paste error from when I was putting together the example for SO.  Thanks